# convert numpy.ndarry to DataFrame maintaining indices after upsampling

Tags: multisampling

```
X_train_1, X_test_1, y_train_1, y_test = train_test_split(x, y,
                                              test_size = .3)

X_train_sam, y_train_sam = ADASYN(random_state=42).fit_sample(X_train_1, y_train_1)

type(X_train_1)
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

X_train_1.shape
(1668, 353)

type(X_train_sam)
numpy.ndarray

X_train_sam.shape
(2698, 353)
```

How can I convert **X_train_sam** back to the dataframe, so that it is the same as **X_train_1** and maintain indices while adding indices to the new data ?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].  What's `ADASYN`, what's `train_test_split()`?

Comment: Please follow the link [mcve].

Comment: Please show us an example or excerpt of `X_train_sam` (presumably a numpy array of some type).  At the very least, show us `X_train_sam.dtype` and `X_train_sam.shape`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
result = pd.DataFrame(X_train_sam)
result.columns = train_1.columns
```

Comment: thanks for that. I will try it but can I have to also convert the y_train, can you have a look at the updated section please

Comment: @Victor: to convert an array or series called `foo` to a DataFrame, simply do `pd.DataFrame(foo)`.

Comment: I like to keep it to one question per question, so please try to work it out and if you're stuck, post a new question specifically about your new issue.

Comment: there you go sir https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48774083/how-to-add-new-index-numbers-to-the-upsampled-data-while-preserving-the-orginal