# How to add new index numbers to the upsampled data while preserving the orginal indices one

Tags: python

I have upsampled my data using the following code

```
X_train_1, X_test, y_train_1, y_test = train_test_split(x, y,
                                          test_size = .3)

X_train, y_train = ADASYN().fit_sample(X_train_1, 
y_train_1)
```

Here is some info about the data

```
type(X_train_1)
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

X_train_1.shape
(1668, 353)

type(X_train)
numpy.ndarray

X_train.shape
(2698, 353)
```

As you can see the data has been upsampled by the number of rows increasing.

Now I want to convert the X_train back to dataframe with the orginal indices while adding new indices to the upsampled

```
result= pd.DataFrame(X_train, index=X_train_1.index)
result.columns = X_train_1.columns
```

The error I get, which makes sense

> Shape of passed values is (353, 2698), indices imply (353, 1668)

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a hack-y way of doing things but it works

To preserve the index, you'll need to include the index in the up_sampling i.e. by reseting the index which

```
# set random_state=0 to reproduce the same result
X_train_1, X_test, y_train_1, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=.3,random_state=0)
# add the index column to the data by resetting index
X_tmp = X_train_1.reset_index()
X_train, y_train = ADASYN().fit_sample(X_tmp, y_train_1)
```

Now we convert `X_train` from `numpy` array to a dataframe with same columns as `X_tmp`, make sure the index column type is int then set the index to the column `index`

```
X_train = pd.DataFrame(X_train,columns=X_tmp.columns)
X_train['index'] = X_train['index'].astype(int)
X_train = X_train.set_index('index')
```

Verify results

```
In [16]: X_tmp.head()
Out[16]: 
   index       0     1         2         3       4         5      6       7
0   1989  1.9750  52.0  2.800000  0.700000   193.0  4.825000  36.73 -119.79
1    256  2.2604  43.0  3.671480  1.184116   836.0  3.018051  37.77 -122.21
2   7887  6.2990  17.0  6.478022  1.087912  1387.0  3.810440  33.87 -118.04
3   4581  1.7199  17.0  2.518000  1.196000  3051.0  3.051000  34.06 -118.28
4   1993  2.2206  50.0  4.622754  1.161677   606.0  3.628743  36.73 -119.81

In [17]: X_train.head()
Out[17]: 
            0     1         2         3       4         5      6       7
index                                                                   
1989   1.9750  52.0  2.800000  0.700000   193.0  4.825000  36.73 -119.79
256    2.2604  43.0  3.671480  1.184116   836.0  3.018051  37.77 -122.21
7887   6.2990  17.0  6.478022  1.087912  1387.0  3.810440  33.87 -118.04
4581   1.7199  17.0  2.518000  1.196000  3051.0  3.051000  34.06 -118.28
1993   2.2206  50.0  4.622754  1.161677   606.0  3.628743  36.73 -119.81
```

As you can see above, the index did not change, it turns out upsampling adds the data to the end of the numpy array, i.e. concatenate the extra data vertically to the original dataframe.values.

even if the above is not the case, you can ensure the order using the following code

```
# get the original data using the original index
X_train_ordered = X_train.loc[X_train_1.index].append(
    # get all new data by looking for indexes not in original data
    X_train.loc[~X_train.index.isin(X_train_1.index)])
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, why wouldnt you also reset the __y_train_1__ index just like with __X_train_1__ to __X_tmp__ ?

Comment: You're welcome. `y_train_1` is the target/label/class/true value; which is expected to be a 1D vector . also keeping track of the index in `X_train_1` is sufficient as `y_train_1` index will be the same